# Thread object constructed by runnable overrides the run method

Tags: java, scjp

Given this sample code:

```
Runnable r = new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
    System.out.print("Cat");
  }
};
Thread t = new Thread(r) {
  public void run() {
    System.out.print("Dog");
  }
};
t.start();
```

why is the output Dog and not Cat??

Comment: (Note in the `Thread` you can do `@Override public void run() { super.run(); System.out.print("Dog"); }`, and you'll get both.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The implementation of `run` in `Thread` simply calls the `Runnable` provided in the constructor, if there is one. You're overriding that code, so if the new thread simply has its `run` method called regardless, the `Runnable` is ignored. Of course, you should be able to look at the source code to check that... (I've just done so, and while I'm not going to post the source here, it does exactly what I've described.)

What you've really exposed is an encapsulation problem - `Thread` *shouldn't* have these different, potentially conflicting, ways of saying what the thread should do. Basically, you should almost *never* extend `Thread` directly. Just because it's been designed badly doesn't mean you have to abuse that poor design ;)

EDIT: This is actually documented, in a somewhat roundabout way. [`start()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#start%28%29) is documented as:

> Causes this thread to begin execution; the Java Virtual Machine calls the run method of this thread.

And [`run()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#run%28%29) is documented as:

> If this thread was constructed using a separate Runnable run object, then that Runnable object's run method is called; otherwise, this method does nothing and returns.

So the `run()` method is called as per `start()`, but you've overridden `run()`, which is the *only* method which will call the `Runnable` provided in the constructor.

Note that if you'd overridden the method like this:

```
Thread t = new Thread(r) {
  public void run() {
    super.run();
    System.out.print("Dog");
  }
};
```

Then the output would be "CatDog".

Comment: I don't follow why it is a bad design.Either one extends `Thread` or passes a `Runnable` as the task that the `Thread` *must* run.This is what the documentation specifies.If this can be misused as per the OP trick question, why is this a bad design?

Comment: @Cratylus: Well for a start, because it doesn't prohibit you abusing it. But more importantly, it doesn't separate the concerns of "starting a new thread to run something" and "what to run". It would have been better (IMO) if `Thread` has been a `final` class and had *forced* you to pass in a `Runnable`.

Comment: I see what you mean.I think you are right, but I have seen code base extending `Thread` and creating custom threads, setting `daemon` as needed and `ThreadGroup` etc prior to `concurrent` package.This seems to be useful (back then) and this would not be possible though if the `Thread` was made as `final`.

Comment: @Cratylus: Why would it not be possible? Which of those tasks requires you to *extend* `Thread` rather than just creating an instance and setting properties? Subclassing should be about changing *behaviour*, not just setting values.

Comment: So you are saying the approach I saw with custom threads like this *was* a bad design?

Comment: @Cratylus: If it was extending `Thread` *just* to set some properties, then yes. There's nothing thread-specific there - it's an abuse of inheritance, IMO.

Answer (score 3):

You have overridden `Thread.run` so that it doesn't execute the runnable.  Instead it just prints "Dog".

Comment: It doesn't *have* to work that way though. The implementation *could* be "If a target `Runnable` has been given, call that - otherwise, call the `run` method." (Actually, `start()` is *documented* to call `run`, but the whole class could have been designed differently.)

Comment: Why does it matter how it *could* have been designed?

Comment: Because you didn't post anything to suggest that it's actually *documented* to run that way. Did you check before you're posting? It could have been implementation-specific, very easily.

Comment: Then you should be *explaining that*. And note that knowing that *one* implementation works that way isn't the same thing as knowing whether it's documented behaviour.

Comment: Since this check is made in the Java source code to `Thread.run()`, which is not a `native` method, how could this vary by implementation?

Answer (score 0):

It is because the function `run()` is overridden. And `t` call this function:

```
public void run() {
System.out.print("Dog");
}
```

You will get the o/p as `cat` when you execute `r.start()` Which will call the function

```
 public void run() {
    System.out.print("Cat");
  }
```

Comment: No, `run()` is not overloaded. It's overridden, which is different... and the rest of your answer doesn't really provide much enlightenment.

Comment: yes its overriding . sorry for the mistake. Have already changed it.

Answer (score 0):

Taking a look at the source code for `java.lang.Thread`:

```
public void run() {
    if (target != null) {
        target.run();
    }
}
```

`target` is the `Runnable` field in the `Thread` that the `Thread(Runnable)` constructor uses to assign your `r` variable. When you override the `run` method in the `Thread`, you're changing the behavior of `run` to call

```
System.out.print("Dog");
```

instead  of calling

```
if (target != null) {
    target.run();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This is an anonymous class and you are redefining/overriding `run`. Are you using the passed-in `Runnable` inside your `run`? No you don't. So the question is, why did you expect it to print `Cat`?

```
 new Thread(r) {
  public void run() {
    System.out.print("Dog");
  }
};
```

Comment: He was asking exactly what you asked. He wanted to know what exactly called his runnable's run method.

Comment: @Brian:I don't ask anything.OP asks why is `Cat` printed.I answered that.Because he ignores `Runnable` passed in.

Comment: But the implementation of `Thread` doesn't necessarily have to work that way, a better answer would have been reminding him that `Thread.run` calls his runnable's run method, and that overriding it removed that behavior.

Comment: You mean that there could be an implementation of `Thread(Runnable target)` that ignores the `target` when the thread is `run`?

Comment: @Brian:`If this thread was constructed using a separate Runnable run object, then that Runnable object's run method is called; otherwise, this method does nothing and returns.`.So this is how it is specified.It is not implementation detail.Taken from http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#run%28%29